# Icon Composer not available with Xcode 4.3?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode4.3

I am trying to locate Icon Composer, which was supposedly downloaded as part of Xcode, however I can't find it, neither in applications nor with the spotlight.

Any ideas where it might be, or if I have to download it separately? If so, where from? I tried looking for it in the App Store, but nothing found.

Edit: I am using Xcode 4.3.2 if that helps.

Comment: This is actually a change that came about in the transition from 4.2 to 4.3

Comment: In XCode 4.4 it was removed.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660736/xcode-4-4-removed-icon-composer-in-developer-tools

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Newer Versions

As of Xcode 4.4, Icon Composer is no longer bundled with the IDE. However, you can still download the program from Apple's developer downloads page ([developer.apple.com/downloads/](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#))

Search for "Graphics Tools" and download the latest version of the tools, which is currently the [version for Xcode 5.1](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/graphics_tools_for_xcode__march_2014/graphics_tools_for_xcode_5.1__march_2014.dmg)

## Older Versions

In Xcode 4.3.1 and up Icon Composer can be located in this directory.

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/

In your applications folder right click on Xcode and click "Show Package Contents."

**EDIT:** to make this answer as complete as possible.

However, In Xcode versions 4.2 and below, Icon composer can still be located in the following directory.

> /Developer/Applications/Utilities

And of course, as Dave DeLong said below, Icon Composer can also be accessed through Xcode by navigating to Xcode Menu >> Open Developer Tool >> Icon Composer.

Comment: Or, more conveniently, Xcode menu → Open Developer Tool → Icon Composer.

Comment: @theReverend see the answer I just added for information applicable to Xcode 4.4 and 4.5. This answer is now out of date.

Answer (score 10):

MDT is correct that the application is now bundled inside of Xcode.app, but there's an easier way to get to it:

[image]

Comment: @benzado why make it harder than it needs to be?

Comment: how else will you know who is l33t and who is n00b?

Comment: @benzado: methinks `n00b` can hardly apply to a frameworks developer that works for Apple

Comment: @NSGod lolz we all know dave is super l33t but what if some luser watches him launch icon composer this way we will have ppl making n00b icons

Comment: @benzado ... Icon Composer is not for making icons. You use Photoshop or Pixelmator or something like that.  Icon Composer is for building a bunch of differently-sized images into a single .icns file.

Answer (score 5):

Icon Composer cannot be used to create icons compatible with Retina macs and the app should no-longer be used. It is no-longer bundled with recent versions of Xcode.

Instead, you create a directory "foobar.iconset" and fill it with png images at the sizes you need, and then drag that into the image well in Xcode - which will then create a .icns file at build time.

Currently, the png files you should create are (none are required but all are recommended):

- icon_16x16.png
- icon_16x16@2x.png
- icon_32x32.png
- icon_32x32@2x.png
- icon_128x128.png
- icon_128x128@2x.png
- icon_256x256.png
- icon_256x256@2x.png
- icon_512x512.png
- icon_512x512@2x.png

You can also create the icns file manually with the `iconutil` command line tool.

Official documentation and more details are at: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked into...

```
/Developer/Applications/Utilities
```

Mine is there.

Comment: ::quip:: "/Developer is so February..."