# png to iconset for xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, icons, osx-mountain-lion

I have a `png` and would like to generate an `icon file` for my `xcode app`. after a long search i found that `mountain lion` does not have `icon composer` anymore and that i should use `iconutil` instead. problem is that `iconutil` exepcts icon files as far as i understood, but i only have a png file. i have a mac only from 3 weeks so i am easyly confused here. what is the proper way to build a icon for my application starting from a png file? (i could also start from a .ico file)

could somebody please explain or point me to a good tutorial?

thanks

best reagards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660736/xcode-4-4-removed-icon-composer-in-develo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end i used a free app called "picture2icon" you can find on the app store.

Comment: picture2icon not free anymore. 10$